# Average columns in reverse, and return sum of those averages in R

Tags: r, function

I'm just starting to learn R for forecasting and analysis purposes, and I've decided to try and create a full package for the forecasting model I'm using (Additive Pickup). I work for a hotel, and one of the things I do on a regular basis is forecast our demand, so this will certainly make this part of my job faster and easier!

I've already created a few functions that will get me a data frame of my pickup numbers, and now I'm working on a function to average a user defined number of columns in that new data frame. I've included code to create some sample data, and the code I'm working on below.

Sample Data:

```
test = data.frame(replicate(10, sample(0:2, 32, rep = TRUE)))
```

Broken Code:

```
averagePickup = function(data, day, periods) {
  # data will be your Pickup Data
  # day is the day you're forecasting for (think row number)
  # periods is the period or range of periods that you need to average (a column or range of columns).
 pStart = ncol(data)
 pEnd = ncol(data) - periods
 row = (day-1)
 new_frame = as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = periods))

 for(i in pStart:pEnd) {
    new_frame[1,i] = mean(data[1:row , i])
  }
 return(sum(new_frame[1,1:i]))
}
```

The goal of this is to iterate backwards from the last column in the data to a user defined period. For example, setting "periods" to 1 should return the sum of the average of the last column only. Setting it to 2 would yield the sum of the averages of the last column and second to last column.

However, when I try to run a test of this I get an error that reads

> Error in [<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1, i, value = 0.9) :    new columns
>   would leave holes after existing columns

Any advice you guys could lend would be so appreciated. Also, let me know if I made absolutely zero sense, and apologies for the essay on this question... Note that this has to iterate backwards because of the way the input data is formatted.

Comment: Please include data to make this reproducible

Comment: Yea... that would probably helpful... You can use this code to get a frame that's similar to what I'm working with.

test = data.frame(replicate(10, sample(0:2, 32, rep = TRUE)))

Applied to my code, I'd want to start at column X10. Let me know if there's anything else that will make this more clear!

Comment: `Day` will be the row number and `periods` is column number. Basically, each row is a day of the week, and each column is an observation period. If you set `day` to 11 and `periods` to 1, the function should take the mean of the first 10 observations in column 1. I've been able to get this working when going from left to right on columns, but can't seem to get it to work going right to left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
averagePickup = function(data, day, periods) {
  # data will be your Pickup Data
  # day is the day you're forecasting for (think row number)
  # periods is the period or range of periods that you need to average (a column or range of columns).
  pStart = ncol(data)
  pEnd = ncol(data) - (periods-1)
  row = (day-1)
  new_frame <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 1, ncol = periods))

  for(i in pStart:pEnd) {
    new_frame[1,1+abs(ncol(data)-i)] <- mean(data[1:row , i])
  }
  return(sum(new_frame[1,1:ncol(new_frame)]))
}

averagePickup(test,1,5)
```

> [1] 7

Comment: YES, this is perfect!

Comment: Now because I'm a total noob and learning, I want to make sure I'm understanding the changes you made. You change `pEnd` to include `(periods-1)`, which I'm guessing allows for `pEnd` to be the same value as `pStart` when `periods` is 1. Only other change I see is where you've added `new_frame[1,1+abs(ncol(data)-i)] <- mean(data[1:row , i])`. I'm guessing this will put the means into the new frame in reverse order? Thanks again for all your help man!

Comment: @VincentLevinger You're very welcome. Correct; the first change was to correct the indexing by 1 position and the 2nd change was to say "put the first mean in the first column of `new_frame` and then increment 1 column further out for each additional mean".

Comment: thanks for the explanation. However, I'm not understanding how that second line adds a new column for each iteration. If we were to use the test data I provided (33 rows, 10 columns), the math looks like it would work out like the following on the first iteration. `new_frame[1, 1 + (10 - 1)]`. As far as I can tell, this would put the first mean in column 10, and then the second mean in column 9, so on and so forth. Am I just misunderstanding your description?

Comment: @VincentLevinger   The column index is `1+abs(ncol(data)-i)`. The first iteration is `pStart:pEnd`, i.e. `i` = 10. The number of columns, `ncol(data)` is 10. Therefore the column index is `1 + abs(10 - 10)` which is 1 + 0 and therefore 1. Remember that `pStart` is defined as `ncol(data)` which is 10. In your comment you wrote that it was 1. You might be confused about how the `for` loop works -- you're doing `for(i in pStart:pEnd)` so the first i is 10. It's not `for(i in 1:pEnd)`, so `i` does not start at 1.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense then. I'll admit my understanding of for loops is lacking, I figured that i (or whatever variable you use there) stood for the iteration number, instead of the first part of the vector that follows. Thanks for taking the time to explain it all!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you're looking for:

colMeans will return the average for each column

```
colMeans(test)
     X1      X2      X3      X4      X5      X6      X7      X8      X9     X10 
1.15625 1.00000 0.90625 1.03125 1.15625 1.09375 0.81250 0.93750 1.15625 0.84375
```

Now, instead of every column, you only want the last `x` columns. `dim` will give you the dimensions of your matrix/dataframe, and the second value is the number of columns.

```
dim(test)[2]
```

You can now subset your dataframe dynamically

```
test[, (dim(test)[2] - x):dim(test)[2]]
```

Finally, plug the subsetted dataframe into the `colMeans` function, and wrap a `sum` around it.

```
sum(colMeans(test[, (dim(test)[2] - x):dim(test)[2]]))
```

Comment: This is close, but it unfortunately doesn't take into account the fact that I don't necessarily want the mean of the entire column. The other answer allows it to be more dynamic in selecting the values that I want to mean together, which is necessary to avoid including "future" observations in the mean. Let me know if I've misunderstood your code though, I'm still VERY new to all this!

Comment: If you need to subset the df by rows 1 through Y, you add those rows as the first argument in the subset. You've already included that syntax in your question. In the example above, this would be sum(colMeans(test[1:row, ...